# Async/Await is not working with node 4.x. Can i have the alternate?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Getting below error when i try to use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) with [NodeJs 4.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/index.html). Any issue with the below sample code or should i use alternate ?

> async function main () {
>             ^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Code Samples:

```
(async function () {

        const intgetIDvalue = await fntest(getID);

     }

 })();

 async function fntest (getID) {
   return await knex
     .select('column1')
     .from('tablename')
     .where('ID',getID)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

try installing [asyncawait](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait). It should work for older node versions. Other alternatives are using a callback or promises.

you'll have to require it

1. `npm install asyncawait`
2. require modules.

   `var async = require('asyncawait/async');`

   `var await = require('asyncawait/await');`
3. perform operations.

   `(async function () {
       const intgetIDvalue = await fntest(getID);
    })();`

Answer (score 0):

Node 4.x Does not support async await out of the box. In your cade I believe that the easiest way to add support to it will be though babel-node.

```
Run npm install babel-cli --save-dev
```

and add this to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node --presets env src/index.js"
  },
```

you may need to change src/index.js by your entry point file.

then install the presets

```
npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

then start your project using

```
npm start
```

this shall do the trick.

The advantage of this over installing asyncawait is that you don't need to change anything in your code, as asyncawait gives you functions that have a similar behavior to async and await operator but does not really transpile your code.

PS: you can specify you presets in a .babelrc file too, feel free to read more about it here https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#file-relative-configuration

Comment: Thanks a lot Victor, I can able to execute the code using babel-node for Async/Await functions.

Answer (score 0):

try async.js http://caolan.github.io/async/

```
var async = require("async");  
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results) {
    // results is now an array of stats for each file
});

async.parallel([
    function(callback) { ... },
    function(callback) { ... }
], function(err, results) {
    // optional callback
});
```